# Flickering in bootstrap <Form.select> when run in firefox

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-select

```
<Form.Select><options>option</option></Form.Select>
```

when I click the select box the dropdown is flickering in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

How are you rendering options through that? It should be like this. Also, you haven't mentioned what version of bootstrap you are using. If it's flickering in Firefox than its not the right code. Something must be wrong with your code somewhere. Did you check console.log in firefox. Press Ctrl + Shift +J in Windows or CMD + Shift + J on a Mac. Use Firefox dev

```
<Form.Select>
<option>Option1</option>
</Form.Select>
```